# Remover todos InfoWindow no google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Como faço para remover todos info.window no google maps.

A maioria dos exemplos dão a seguinte maneira:

```
var infowindow = null;

incia

se clicar

if(infowindow){
        infowindow.close();
}
```

Meu código está assim:

```
<script>
var infowindow = null;
```

//Restante do código google maps...

```
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

    if(infowindow){
        infowindow.close();
    }
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var iwContent = 'FOI';

    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));     
    infoWindow.open(map);

  });
```

Como faço para corrigir? pois ele só retorna a váriavel NULL ...

Answer (score -1):

Para funcionar eu tenho que fazer o seguinte:

```
 map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

    if(infoWindow){
        infoWindow.close();
    }

    var iwContent = 'FOI';
    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));     
    infoWindow.open(map);   
  });


  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

ATT